# A typical SQL Query in Erlang and Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I want some help in writing a typical SQL query in Erlang. I just want to prevent logging the offline message based on this query.

Want to put this query at start of this function.

```
store_offline_msg(Host, {User, _Server}, Msgs, Len, MaxOfflineMsgs, odbc) ->
    Count = if MaxOfflineMsgs =/= infinity ->
           Len + count_offline_messages(User, Host);
           true -> 0
        end,
    if Count > MaxOfflineMsgs -> discard_warn_sender(Msgs);
```

**Mysql Table**

```
 ID  | user         |  touser          | starttime           | end
 586 | my_gmail.com | touser_gmail.com | 2014-10-29 14:03:16 |  60
```

Query I need is to check:

**if 'user' and 'touser' have a record in this table, and current time comes in between starttime and startime + end (60 seconds)**

Please help me in this, I appreciate it.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking (1) how to write a SQL query, (2) how to talk to MySQL from Erlang, or (3) how to use the results of the SQL query to influence ejabberd.

Comment: I just want help in writing this sql query in erlang, which should be in Ejabberd way. I will write same query simply in SQL and then you can write it again in erlang if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how I implemented it and solved my problem.**

```
 Check = case catch ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
            LServer,
            ["select id from archive_disable_user"
             "  where ( ( user ='", To, "' "
             "  and tuser='",  From , "' ) "
             "  or ( user ='", From, "' "
             "  and tuser='",  To , "' ) )"
             "  and ( ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) + end ) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()); "]) of
           {selected, ["id"], Rs} -> 
               Rcheck = len(Rs),
               if 
                Rcheck == 0 ->
                  false;
                true->                  
                  true
                end;         
           _-> false
          end,       
   Check.
```